# Is there a nice description of the field of fractions of the ring of polynomials with integer coefficients?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ denote the ring of polynomials (in the formal variable $x$) with integer coefficients. Since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an integral domain, we can form its field of quotients, call it $Q.$

Is there a nice description of $Q$? I don't think $Q = \mathbb{Q}((x)),$ or in other words I don't think $Q = $ the set of all formal Laurent polynomials with rational coefficients, because for example I think that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \notin Q.$$

Comment: Is $Q = \mathbb{Q}(x)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{Q}$ nice enough?

Comment: @DanielFischer, yeah, especially if you can provide a link where I can learn more. ;)

Comment: What more do you want to learn?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, for starters, is $\mathbb{Z}$ in some sense the simplest ring $R$ such that $R(x) \cong \mathbb{Q}(x)$? But for example, I don't know what the appropriate notion of 'simplest' is, which is why a reference would be nice.

Comment: @user18921 When you write "$R(x)\cong \Bbb Q(x)$" do you actually mean "is $\Bbb Z$ the 'simplest' ring whose polynomial ring has field of fractions equal to $\Bbb Q(x)$?" $\Bbb Q$ also has that property. Since the characteristic of $\Bbb Q(x)$ is zero, any such $R$ would also have to have characteristic zero, but $\Bbb Z$ injects into any ring with characteristic zero,  making it pretty "small" compared to the other potential $R$'s.

Comment: We always have ${\rm Frac}(R)(x)\cong{\rm Frac}(R[x])$ (here $R$ an integral domain), so the question of the "simplest" $R$ whose polynomial ring has fraction field $F(x)$ becomes the question of the simplest $R$ which has fraction field $F$. In the case of $F=\Bbb Q$ this is obviously just $R=\Bbb Z$ because this is the unique minimal unital subring (any such subring needs to have $1$ so needs to have all the integers).

Comment: What is $\mathbb Q((x))$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you've found an injection of a domain $D$ into a field $F$, there's just one thing to check before concluding that $F$ is (isomorphic to) the field of fractions for $D$: you need to check that $D$ is "dense" in $F$ in the following sense.

> For any $q\in F\setminus\{0\}$, there exists $d\in D$ such that $qd\in D\setminus\{0\}$.

If $D$ has field of fractions $Q$, and $D$ is also embedded in a field $F$, you are always going to have an injection $Q\to F$. The above condition, if it is satisfied, guarantees the injection is also a *surjection*, and in that case $Q$ and $F$ would be isomorphic fields.

Now $\Bbb Z[x]$ can be identified as a subset of $\Bbb Q(x)$ as elements of the form $\frac{p(x)}{1}$ where $p(x)$ is an integer polynomial. Given an arbitrary nonzero element $\frac{s(x)}{t(x)}\in \Bbb Q(x)$, find the least common multiple of denominators of coefficents of $s(x)$ and of $t(x)$ and call them $m$ and $m'$ respectively. Then $m\cdot m'\cdot t(x)\in \Bbb Z[x]$ and $(m\cdot m'\cdot t(x))\frac{s(x)}{t(x)}\in \Bbb Z[x]\setminus\{0\}$. So, $\Bbb Z[x]$ is "dense" in $\Bbb Q(x)$ and therefore $\Bbb Q(x)$ is the field of fractions for $\Bbb Z[x]$.

This also helps us see why $\Bbb Q((x))$ *isn't* the field of fractions for $\Bbb Z[x]$. Certainly $\Bbb Z[x]$ is contained in $\Bbb Q((x))$, but the field is too big, and $\Bbb Z[x]$ isn't dense in it! The field $\Bbb Q((x))$ contains power series $S$ such that $S$ does not lie in $\Bbb Q(x)$, and if it were to happen that $dS=d'$ for nonzero $d,d'$ in $\Bbb Z{x}$, then $\frac{d'}{d}=S$ lying in $\Bbb Q(x)$ would be a contradiction.

Comment: Cannot one multiply $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i$ by the integer polynomial $1-x$ to obtain the nonzero constant integer polynomial $1$?

Comment: @anon Gah, of course... that is the example that rolled out of my head, but clearly it is not the right one...

Comment: @anon Thank so much for bringing this to my attention. I made edits accordingly. I remember one of my colleagues writing a nifty paper on identifying the rational power series. If I remember correctly, nonperiodic sequences should yield irrational elements of $\Bbb Q((x))$. I was going to suggest $\sum x^i/2^i$ but now I am second guessing the examples I think up here :)

Comment: @rschwieb Does this answer say that $\mathbb Z(x)= \mathbb Q(x)$?

Comment: @rschwieb It seems we immediately have $\mathbb Z(x)=\mathbb Q(x)$ by the following: We know $\mathbb Z(x) \subset \mathbb Q(x)$; and since $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Z(x)$, then $\mathbb Q[x] \subset \mathbb Z(x)$, hence $\mathbb Q(x) \subset \mathbb Z(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @AlJebr I think it’s easier just to show that every element of $Q(x)$ is equivalent to an element of $Z(x)$.  Obviously, since you just need to multiply by $z/z$ for some integer z to convert a rational rational function into an integer rational function.